# Push data and key into array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a array in `data()` :

```
data()  {
  return {
    list: [],
 }
},

methods: {
  pushData() {
     this.list.push({name:'yorn', age: 20});
  }
}
```

Now I want to push to the 'list' array of the following format, The key is `info`:

```
list [
     info [
     {
       name:yorn,
       age: 20
     }
  ]
 ]
```

I'm new to vuejs and javascript so I need everyone's help. Please give me your opinion. Thanks

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to push to the 'list' array of the following format, The key is
> `info`
>
> list: [
> info: [
> {
> name:yorn,
> age: 20
> }   ] ]

The above expected result is not a valid `JSON`. It should be like below **:**

```
list: [{
    info: [{
        name: yorn,
        age: 20
    }]
}]
```

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.pushData();
  },
  methods: {
    pushData() {
      this.list.push({info : [{name:'yorn', age: 20}] });
      // Or you can also use below one.
      // this.list[0].info.push({name:'yorn', age: 20});
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(obj, index) in list" :key="index">
    <p v-for="(item, i) in obj.info" :key="i">{{ item.name }}       </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I expected. Thank you for your help with my work

Answer (score 1):

Try altering the `pushData` method to have `data` parameter

```
pushData(data) {
 this.list.push(data);
}
```

Invoke the method

```
this.pushData({name: "john", age: 25});
```

Comment: Thanks @Nader. But I want an external `info ` key, can you suggest me?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need smth like:
```
const info = [{name: "john", age: 25}];
this.pushData(info)
```
This will result in a list array with the first index being another array (info).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you are trying to create a nested array. However, in an array you don't use a key but an index. What you are looking for is called an associative array.

**Option a:** Use the index of a 'normal' array

```
list = [{name: 'abc', age: 10},{name: 'def', age: 20}]
```

This way you can use the data in your array by using the index:

```
list[0] == {name: 'abc', age: 10}

list[1] == {name: 'def', age: 20}
```

**Option b:** Use an associative array

```
list = { info1: {name: 'abc', age: 10}, info2: {name: 'def', age: 20}}
```

This way you can use a key instead of an index. You just need different brackets for an associative array.

Hope this is helpful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use like below

```
pushData() {
 let data = { info : [{name:'yorn', age: 20}] }
 this.list.push(data);
```

}

Hope this is helpful. :-)